# Making a query issue

Tags: php, mysql

i'm making a query to insert some values to a table and update other in other table all this in the same function.

The problem i have is with the Insert query, when has been execute, give me a syntax error that you can see below.

[image: capture]

I reviewed the code many times but i don't see any error. When I remove the Insert query works fine and if I remove de update query and leave just the insert give me the same error.

Here the query

```
if (isset($_POST['goodalt']) && isset($_POST['gengood'])){
    $goodalt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['goodalt']);
    $genid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gengood']);
        $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `generators` WHERE `name` = '$genid'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $genname = $row['name'];
        }
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`username`, `accs`, `genid`, `gen-name`, `date`, `status`) VALUES ('$username', '$goodalt', '$genid', '$genname', '$date', '1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `generator$genid` SET `status` = '3' WHERE `alt` = '$goodalt'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: put the `"` outside `)` .     *mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`username`, `accs`, `genid`, `gen-name`, `date`, `status`) VALUES ('$username', '$goodalt', '$genid', '$genname', '$date', '1')" or die(mysqli_error($con));*

Comment: Why you used `generator$genid` for table name ?

Comment: @Ajay thanks but don't work error 500

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna because each generator have your own table and I identify the table with id example: Generator1, generator2 it's more easy for me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a close bracket in your insert...

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`username`, `accs`, `genid`, `gen-name`, `date`, `status`) VALUES ('$username', '$goodalt', '$genid', '$genname', '$date', '1')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

BUT you should also be using prepared statements and bind variables...

Answer (score 1):

Apart form error, there is a BIG issue about concurrency and threading model.
Every time you split INSERT/UPADATE in more separate PHP calls two mysql, you can analyze CAREFULLY if separate queries maintain DB consistent.

Consider carefully is two (or more) web requests (executing the same PHP script) can be safely run in parallel, especially on code where You did:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`username`, `accs`, `genid`, `gen-name`, `date`, `status`) VALUES ('$username', '$goodalt', '$genid', '$genname', '$date', '1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `generator$genid` SET `status` = '3' WHERE `alt` = '$goodalt'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Insert and Updates are atomic, but here you call two separate queries

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're facing is because of the unnecessary usage of backticks or single quotation marks. You can follow the following article to make the changes and the issue should be sorted out.

Article [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Change these from:

```
 mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `user_accounts` (`username`, `accs`, `genid`, `gen-name`, `date`, `status`) VALUES ('$username', '$goodalt', '$genid', '$genname', '$date', '1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

to

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user_accounts (username, accs, genid, gen-name, date, status) VALUES ('$username', '$goodalt', '$genid', '$genname', '$date', '1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the opposite of helpful! If in doubt, test before answering!

Comment: Done but same error and i don't know why i use same query in others files